# Azure ServiceBus - Lock supplied is invalid

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues

I have my Azure Function app which triggers on new service bus message queue. My first few message get successfully processed but after a certain time I start getting following error:
*" Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus: The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue. "*

What is the reason and how can I fix this??

Host.Json file:

```
{
  "functionTimeout": "05:05:00",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 100,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": true,        
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "05:00:00"
      }     
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the prefetch your function app is configured with and max function duration?

Comment: Max function duration?? Where do I configure that?

Comment: Maximum time your function execute, that's what I meant.

Comment: And on the ASB side - lock duration on the queue. Often, too short of a duration causes message lock to be lost, causing the error.

Comment: I configured the Function "functionTimeout" property as 5 hrs still I get the lock error. Where do i configure the lock duration of ASB??

Comment: Function will never run for 5 hours on a consumption plan. Look at your triggering entity  max lock duration setting, what is it? And what's in your function that you need 5h?! Are you processing something that long? And if not, what's the maximum function execution time? Focus on answering these two first.

Comment: lock duration I have kept is for 5 mins and maxAutoRenewDuration as 5 hrs. My SB is receiving messages around 500 messages one by one and each message is processed by Azure Function where it queries a blob storage and copy a blob content in a Azure table storage. approximately 30 to 40 secs. Function trigger is Service Bus Receiving Message in a topic.

Comment: updated question with the host file of Function

Comment: Prefetch 100 means you are grabbing up to 100 messages per receiver, with 32 receivers in total. If a single message takes up to 40 seconds, you're way out of time to complete all 100 while the clock has started ticking for all of those messages since the moment they were prefetched. Lower your prefetch.

Comment: Starting again with prefetch as 1

Comment: With 40 secs processing time, a prefetch of 10 sounds reasonable. I have added an answer, as now there are enough details to understand what the problem was. You might want to switch to comments under the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using the latest version of the extension. If that is not 4.1.1 please upgrade it . ref: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/38

In case such a issue occurs, the recommendation will be to use the service bus explorer tool to check the deadletter reason. The following document mentions details related to dead lettering in service bus and the various reasons for a message to get dead lettered: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues

e.g. : if the issue is with the delivery count you may increase MaxDeliveryCount to its maximum value ( i.e. 10)

You may may try to implement the retry logic explicitly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions#messagelocklostexception https://github.com/jeffhollan/functions-csharp-queue-exponential/blob/master/ExponentialRetry.cs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#service-bus

Here are few relevant links which you can refer to :

The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue - due to AutoComplete defaulting to true. After updating the value to false it was resolved.

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/802#issuecomment-294879874 – After switching to NetMessaging protocol from AMQP issue got resolved.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b86a64bb-cfcf-422b-a5fb-d831b7702c29/getting-an-exception-message-handler-encountered-an-exception?forum=servbus – After using “ReceiveandDelete” mode issue got resolved.

However, we recommend “PeekLock”.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the prefetch size that is likely causing cached messages to lose their lock tokens and throw the exception when attempted to be completed after function is done with those.

Reducing the prefetch count should help. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2#prefetching) goes into details of why this could be the case. Long story short, prefetched message time starts ticking from the moment it's received, not started processing. If the message sits too long in cache, the client will still process it and throw an exception.